# Firebase notification to particular user from android device

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

Ive successfully implemented my **php app server**.My android device can receive notifications with data payload. Now i want to send notification with datapayload from my **device** to a **specific user device**.

My case: **Visitor has came to meet employeeA  reception notifies only employeeA**.

Do I need to implement a xmpp server? or my php server can also handle this mechanism?
i tried referencing for xmpp server https://github.com/carlosCharz/fcmxmppserver. But libraries were deprecated.
any help would be  appreciated

Comment: I'd recommend a much simpler approach, highlighted here: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html

Answer (score 0):

Base url: https://fcm.googleapis.com - 404 The requested URL / was not found on this server.

Answer (score -1):

All you need to send notification to specific user device is device token.

So you could do this in two ways:

1. Ask server for concrete token and send request via firebase from device
2. Ask server to send request to some device.

So you must hold devices tokens on server. If you collect this info with connection to users accounts you could send notifications from one user to another

---

There is a [code snippet](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/614729/17609) to send notification to concreate device from android application via [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) library:

```
MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

//in JSON field "to" is target device token.
//you can get it so: FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
//but, ofcause, you must get it from i.e. server
String json = "{ 
   \"notification\": {
    \"title\": \"news\",
    \"text\": \"newsTExt\",
     \"click_action\": \"test\"
  },
    \"data\": {
    \"keyname\": \"any value\"
    },
  \"to\" : \"dAQilNw:APA91IFd666h7WVSlAOyS-WraSrGv_IRZM\"
}"

String keyFromConsole = ...;//here is key from firebase console (Settings-prohect settings-CLOUD MESSAGING-server key)

RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .url("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send")
      .addHeader("Authorization", "key=" + keyFromConsole)
      .addHeader("ContentType", "application/json")
      .post(body)
      .build();


Response response = client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

  @Override public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
  }

  @Override public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(response.body().string());
  }
});
```

Comment: Are you suggesting me to keep the server key on device?

Comment: This is always an option. If yiu dont want it, send reqest from server

Comment: Yes there you go .. which server should i implement in order to that my app can receive a notification and simultaneously it can send the notification to other specific device? @mohax

Comment: @SaketMarwad, you can use any server that you can imagine. It can be a `php` script or you can use some android device as server) Just send push to it, catch it and execute code from anwer.

Comment: extremely sorry to bother you sir. Im a bit confused when i tried relating my scenario with firebase [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#implementing-http-connection-server-protocol) it says ill have to implement a xmpp protocol .. if you could suggest me some tutorial that would be great ..

Comment: Keeping the Firebase Cloud Messaging **server** key on a *end-user device* is a security risk. Anyone who has that key can send messages to users of the app on your behalf.

Comment: @SaketMarwad, as I understand docs it's an option. You could use just http requests

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yes i get the risk of keeping server key on device. but im not getting how to receive _deviceA's notification on php app server  and send it to deviceB using http requests_ ,as suggested by mohax. i tried to search for similar references but no luck. though i was able to send notification from my php app server manually.

Comment: @mohax can you give me some references. im unable to find those. though i was able to send notification from my php app server manually

Comment: @mohax Can you give me a link for where in the documentation you understood that it's an option to keep the server key on the device? I'll make sure it gets clarified.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, I meen that you could store it on device. I dont meen that you should do it and that it's a good idea. In answer I just show how to send notification via http request

Answer (score -1):

You do not need device token. You do not need to implement a xmpp protocol. Subscribe devices to topic. Send notification from one device to other with Retrofit.

```
public void onClick(View view) {

    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request original = chain.request();

            // Request customization: add request headers
            Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                    .header("Authorization", "key=legacy server key from FB console"); // <-- this is the important line
            Request request = requestBuilder.build();
            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    });

    httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);
    OkHttpClient client = httpClient.build();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://fcm.googleapis.com")//url of FCM message server
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())//use for convert JSON file into object
            .build();

    // prepare call in Retrofit 2.0
    FirebaseAPI firebaseAPI = retrofit.create(FirebaseAPI.class);

    //for messaging server
    NotifyData notifydata = new NotifyData("Notification title","Notification body");

Call<Message> call2 = firebaseAPI.sendMessage(new Message("/topics/news", notifydata));

    call2.enqueue(new Callback<Message>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Message> call, Response<Message> response) {

            Log.d("Response ", "onResponse");
            t1.setText("Notification sent");

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Message> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("Response ", "onFailure");
            t1.setText("Notification failure");
        }
    });
}
```

POJOs

```
public class Message {
String to;
NotifyData notification;

public Message(String to, NotifyData notification) {
    this.to = to;
    this.notification = notification;
}

}
```

and

```
public class NotifyData {
String title;
String body;

public NotifyData(String title, String body ) {

    this.title = title;
    this.body = body;
}

}
```

and FirebaseAPI

```
public interface FirebaseAPI {

@POST("/fcm/send")
Call<Message> sendMessage(@Body Message message);

}
```